# Sorting of list by matching the 'input' lists in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, matching

I have a (probably quite simple) problem I cannot figure out in Python.

Say I have a list 
`X1 = [1,2,3]` 
with the corresponding list 
`Y1 = [5,6,7]` 
and a list 
`X2 = [2,1,3]` 
with corresponding list 
`Y2 = [8,9,10]`
where `X1` and `X2` contain the same values but in different order. How can I match the order of `X2` to that of `X1`, while the `X2` `Y2` pairs remain intact? The answer should be then `Y2 = [9,8,10]`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = len(X1)
inds = range(n)
d = {X2[i_]:Y2[i_] for i_ in inds}   
nY2 = [d[X1[i_]] for i_ in inds]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
[Y2[X1.index(x)] for x in X2]
```

This has a O(n^2) time complexity, if you build a dictionary with X1's indices before, you can get O(n) time complexity:

```
d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(X1)}
[Y2[d[x]] for x in X2]
```

Comment: Note: if you use the second method, `X1` and `X2` absolutely need to have the same elements in them or it will break.

Answer (score 0):

u can play with zip

Your Code:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = [5, 6, 7]

x2 = [2, 1, 3]
y2 = [8, 9, 10]
```

Step 1 zip the lists:

```
z1 = list(zip(x1, y1))    
z2 = list(zip(x2, y2))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
[(2, 8), (1, 9), (3, 10)]
```

Step 2 sort the new lists:

```
z1.sort()
z2.sort()
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 10)]
```

Step 3 list zip them again with *

```
z1 = list(zip(*z1))
z2 = list(zip(*z2))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 7)]
[(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 10)]
```

NOW put the values back:

```
x1 = z1[0]
y1 = z1[1]
x2 = z2[0]
y2 = z2[1]
```

OUTPUT:

```
x1 = (1, 2, 3)
y1 = (5, 6, 7)
x2 = (1, 2, 3)
y2 = (9, 8, 10)
```

Remember x1, x2, y1, y2 is now tuple if u want to be list u need one more step

```
x1 = list(x1)
x2 = list(x2)
y1 = list(y1)
y2 = list(y2)
```

Output:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = [5, 6, 7]
x2 = [1, 2, 3]
y2 = [9, 8, 10]
```